# Why is my sip software calling 105

Tags: voip, sip, xlite

I have a very bad sip provider "vbuzzer" but there prices are cheap ,they don't have an app for android (there is one in the store but i am pretty sure it is not official ,and a scam) and their windows software is bad programmed 
so i was thinking of using another sip software to make the calls for both windows and android phone

when i used x-lite and micro-sip software to make calls i get a voice message telling me that the number is not in service ,luckily in vbuzzer website have an interface showing you the dialed number ,in there i always find that i called 105 while i am in fact calling my number(00+country code+ phone number) !

when i call my number from their software it works fine (but have a lot of other issues like lag)

I don't know what i did wrong so that the sip software will call 105 instead of my number

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that your SIP SW is calling another number than you typed in, especially since you have "a very bad SIP provider"? What is "your number" -- is it your landline, which is operated by another provider? Either way, it's either the case that you can't clal landlines or you can't call yourself, and it looks as if your "bad provider" handlöes this by a redirection to 105. So why don't you ask _them_?

Comment: like i said,when i use their software to call my number it works fine,and it is my mobile number and they a have a very bad customer service too, google them to read some reviews

Comment: I use them. For the price they are adequate. From your question it seems to me that you are trying to use other software to run vbuzzer. I don't think they allow 3rd party software to access their system

Comment: @Xavierjazz yes,they do
 http://forum.vbuzzer.com/viewtopic.php?t=864

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much! I've been a user for a number of years now, and I asked for this service, but you know how little they respond. Have a great day and good luck. I'm going to try.

Comment: @Xavierjazz  you are welcome,can you at least help me with some testing ? try to setup a sip software with your account info ,and tell me the result ,you will find the calls info in here https://www.vbuzzer.com/account/my_call_detail_tab.php ,did you find a way to run it on your phone ?

Comment: I am very ignorant as to how to implement this, I'm afraid, and I am at the moment too busy to take the time to understand it. I want to use outlook to dial out since then I can keep info about the call in outlook.

Comment: Perhaps in the new year, when you have enough rep we can discuss through chat?

Comment: @Xavierjazz of course